# Chrome webrtc-internals showing audioLevel as 0 and there is no audio

Tags: webrtc, kurento, openwebrtc

I am using Kurento for audio-only Webrtc. We have two browser apps from where users can connect and listen. But for one of the app, there is no audio in Chrome. And in other browsers it is working fine. Also, the other app works perfectly fine in Chrome. For the app, for which there is no audio, I checked chrome://webrtc-internals/, I found `audioLevel`, `totalAudioEnergy` and `[Audio_Level_in_RMS` as 0. Which seems like the issue. But I am not able to find the reason why it is 0 as same stream is being audible with non-zero `audio` attributes.

[image]

SDP Offer generated from chrome:

```
v=0
o=- 5216768741743449485 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:RqhJ
a=ice-pwd:nzZ+GB+RAJ6H80ToE7uxpaZk
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 49:17:98:CC:EE:53:46:B4:A0:86:3B:29:B8:E4:E5:E8:E1:CD:49:B0:B5:AA:D8:3A:68:EF:2D:96:31:FF:F9:AE
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
```

SDP Answer from Kurento:

```
v=0
o=- 3788596538 3788596538 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=Kurento Media Server
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
a=group:BUNDLE 0
m=audio 1 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 0
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendonly
a=mid:0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=setup:active
a=rtcp-mux
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=ssrc:4159551798 cname:user3791831093@host-88916abf
a=ice-ufrag:dfqB
a=ice-pwd:nvfOteYfAIimzPMmD1E1Gx
a=fingerprint:sha-256 E5:D2:D9:1E:82:DD:21:E4:1B:8F:FC:62:F6:2C:FF:5B:C3:C4:17:75:97:DB:F0:BC:B5:F2:2C:6A:EB:35:83:4E
```

Any thoughts/suggestions/debug steps? Please share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be a codec issue. Could you please post your SDP reply from Kurento:

Comment: Thanks for looking @IgorKhvostenkov. Added SDP offer and received answer in question.

Comment: Codecs look good. Looks like either you broadcast some silent dummy audio track or remote stream is muted. Can you confirm that `receiver.track.muted` for remote stream returns false?

Comment: Well, I can listen to audio from other browsers. But could you add more colors how I can check `receiver.track.muted`? Any example would help

Comment: Okay, I checked `receiver.track.muted` and it is false.

Comment: Ok, this becomes interesting. What is the difference between 2 apps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206420/discussion-between-hemu-and-igor-khvostenkov).